# In a iOS Shortcuts workflow, how do I select the “home” phone number specifically?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I can already create a script that selects the first phone number by adding these workflow cards:

- Contacts [Contact Selected]
- Get Details of Contacts [Phone Number]
- Get Item from List [First Item]

But i cant find any way to automatically select “home” or “work” specifically without a user prompt.

I have tried dictionary keys.

I have also tried adding a Text card with [Details of Contacts] variable but that does not contain home or work text.